# Delete after CTE

Tags: azure-sql-database

Im using an azure dwh server and try to delete duplicate records. Normally i would do it using a CTE like this:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
    HashTagID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY
                HashTagID
            ORDER BY
                HashTagID
        ) row_num
     FROM
        [dbo].[ref_Tag]
       
)
Delete FROM cte
WHERE row_num > 1;
```

But that gets a "Failed to generate query plan." because i cant use delete after a CTE on the DWH.

So i tried rewriting the statement to this:

```
Delete dup from (SELECT
HashTagID,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY
            HashTagID
        ORDER BY
            HashTagID
    ) row_num
 FROM
    [dbo].[ref_Tag]) as dup WHERE row_num > 1
```

But i get the same error.

The records are exactly the same. Even the key. so i have to somehow count the times the same record is there and then delete the 2nd occurance. I'd like to keep one of the dupes.

Does anyone know how to write this statement to work on the azure dwh?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think we can do it directly as we do it through CTE in sql server.

But you can try something like below to achieve it. Here I used one column table. ***If you have more columns, you can 'group by' in first query.***
`

```
Create Table dbo.ref_tag_temp
with (distribution = ROUND_ROBIN , clustered columnstore index) 
as select distinct HashTagID from 
dbo.ref_Tag

delete from  [dbo].[ref_Tag];

INSERT INTO [dbo].[ref_Tag]
select * from  dbo.ref_tag_temp;

drop table  dbo.ref_tag_temp;
```

`